# Delphi TListView DynamicApperance works in Windows, but not works on Android

Tags: android, delphi, rad-studio

I am struggling a problem in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.4

I create a Multi Device Application in Delphi, I have tabs that contains TListView lists in DynamicApperance. In Toogle DesignMode I set four TTextObjectApperances, then I fill it some text from a webservice.

The result in Windows target is OK, but when I load on Android there isn't OK the apperance.

Tab2:
[image]

Tab3:
[image]

My code:

```
procedure TForm14.TabItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: integer;
  LVI: TListViewItem;
  LPhs: Purchase_Headers;
  LHeadersCount: integer;
begin
  LPHs := GetPurchHeaderList();
  LHeadersCount := GWMS.HeadersCount();
  j :=0;
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
  repeat
    LVI := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LVI.Data['Text1'] := LPHs[j].No;
    LVI.Data['Text2'] := LPHs[j].Pay_to_Name;
    LVI.Data['Text3'] := LPHs[j].Expected_Receipt_Date;
    LVI.Data['Text4'] := LPHs[j].Vendor_Shipment_No;
    j := j+1;
  until j=LHeadersCount;
  ListView2.EndUpdate;
end;



procedure TForm14.TabItem3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: integer;
  LVI: TListViewItem;
  LPhs: Purchase_Headers;
  LHeadersCount: integer;

begin
  LPHs := GetPurchHeaderList();
  LHeadersCount := GWMS.HeadersCount();
  j :=0;
  ListView2.BeginUpdate;
  ListView2.Items.Clear;
  try

   for j := 0 to LHeadersCount-1
    do begin
      LVI := ListView2.Items.Add;
      LVI.Data['PH_no'] := LPHs[j].No;
      LVI.Data['PH_name'] := LPHs[j].Pay_to_Name;
      LVI.Data['PH_ship'] := LPHs[j].Expected_Receipt_Date;
      LVI.Data['PH_vendno'] := LPHs[j].Vendor_Shipment_No;
    end;

  finally
    ListView2.EndUpdate;
  end;
```

It seems the Android can't take the DynamicApperance layout, on the Tab2 only find the Item.Text1 ApperanceObjectName, on the Tab3 can't find any ApperanceObjectName. The Android version is 9, the phone is Urovo DT50. (I've been tried Realme 6 in Android 10, but same faulty appearance)

Can somebody help me please?